# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{[x]1!+2![2x]+\dots+[nx]n!}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate 
>   $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{[x]1!+2![2x]+....+[nx]n!}{(n+1)!},$$ 
>   where $[x]$, $[2x]$, $[nx]$ are the floor functions (the greatest integer function).

Now, the only idea that i have is to apply the squeeze theorem at some point but first i thought to make use of the property :$x-1<[x]\le x$.( the thing is i didn't get far) .

Comment: $x$ is a constant in this limit, so the numerator is greater than $(x-1)(1!+2!\cdot 2+3!\cdot 3+\dots+n!\cdot n)$ which I think collapses to $(x-1)((n+1)!-1)$...  I guess the trick will be how to calculate the difference between the result of this limit and $[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. By [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{[x]1!+2![2x]+\dots+[nx]n!}{(n+1)!}
\stackrel{SC}{=}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{[(n+1)x](n+1)!}{(n+2)!-(n+1)!}
=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{[(n+1)x]}{(n+2)-1}=?$$

Comment: how did the numerator converge to ${[(n+1)x](n+1)!}$

Comment: @ibuprofen At the first step I applied SC: if $a(n)=[x]1!+2![2x]+\dots+[nx]n!$ then $a(n+1)-a(n)=[(n+1)x](n+1)!$.

Comment: Thank you ! So just to double-check, the answer  is x, right?

Comment: @Jon9 Yes, that's correct.